# window.name loses its value if excuted from localhost

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-domain, internet-explorer-11

I was working on passing some values through the `window.open` which works fine and then I noticed I don't receive the values if the window has been opened from localhost!

```
var newTab = window.open(theURL, theValue);
```

I can't seem to find any explanation? I can pass the value cross domains with no issues.

I tried that in IE 11 and its the only place I need this to work on (Can't find another option)

Comment: You can use [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) API.

Comment: It doesn't work with IE11 "cross-domain" this is why I'm implementing this for IE 11 only